# Compute the limit of $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\sin (nx)$ when $n\to\infty$, for $f \in L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Find
>   $$
> \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\sin(nx) dx \,.
> $$

LDCT is a no go, as well as MCT and FL, which are really the only integration techniques we've developed thus far in the course. Integration by parts isn't applicable either since we just have $f \in L^1$. I've tried splitting both $f$ and $\sin(nx)$ into unsigned parts but that didn't seem to help. I don't think using the density of $C_c(\mathbb{R}) \subset L^1$ will help either. I've tried approximating $f$ by simple functions, but that didn't seem to do the trick either..

To give you a gauge in regards to where we are at, we just finished basic properties of $L^p$ spaces and will begin Hilbert Space Theory as in Big Rudin.

Any **hints** are greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** Let $h \in C^1_c(\mathbb{R})$ be such that $\sup \limits_{x \in X}|f(x)-h(x)| < \epsilon.$ Let $\operatorname{supp}(h) = [a,b]$. Then,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} h(x)\sin(nx) \, dx &=& \int_{[a,b]} h(x)\sin(nx) \, dx \\
&=& \left[h(x) \frac{\cos(nx)}{n} \right] + \int_{[a,b]} \frac{1}{n} f'(x) \cos(nx) \, dx \\
\end{eqnarray*}

note that since $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, it is bounded by some $M$. Thus, $\frac{1}{n}f'(x)\cos(nx) \leq \frac{M}{n}$, which converges to $0$ uniformly. Taking limits yields that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\sin(nx) dx = 0.$$

Alternatively, if we use a simple function approximation, we end up with something of the form $$\int_\mathbb{R} \sum_{i=1}^{k}c_i \chi_{E_i}(x)\sin(nx)dx = \sum_{i=1}^k c_i \int_{E_i} \sin(nx)dx$$ which goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ (The $E_i$'s can be chosen to be disjoint), but the below question still remains.

*How does this follow from the fact that we've only used a dense subset?*

Comment: Are you able to prove the result for a dense subset of functions ? You may for example use the density of $\mathcal{C}^1_c(\mathbb{R})$ and use integration by parts.

Comment: @JoelCohen I understand that this would make the first term vanish, but why does $f$ need be differentiable?

Comment: You need the differentiability to perform the integration by parts in the first place (differentiate $f$ and integrate the sine, yielding a $\frac{1}{n}$ factor).

Comment: @JoelCohen Yes I understand, this would send everything to $0$, since $\frac{1}{n} f' \cos(nx) \to 0$ uniformly. I was forgetting that $C^1$ implies that $f$ **and** it's derivative are differentiable

Comment: @AnthonyPeter Actually, $\mathcal C^1$ means that the function is differentiable and its derivative is continuous, but not necessarily differentiable.

Comment: @Farnight typo. I meant continuous.

Comment: The point is that even smooth functions with compact support are dense in $L^1$.

Comment: You've proven that the left hand side is $0$ on a dense subset. So if you can show that it is continuous, that should be enough.

Comment: @Farnight *it* is continuous? What does "it" refer to?

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant the "big" function $$\mathcal F(f) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_\mathbb R f(x)\sin(nx)\mathop{\mathrm dx}$$

You need to show that it's continuous with respect to the $L^1$ norm. But first, you'll need to show that it's well defined.

Comment: @Farnight Well-defined in what sense? That $\mathcal{F}(f)$ has a single value? I don't see how this differs much from the original problem

Comment: "I've tried approximating $f$ by simple functions, but that didn't seem to do the trick either." I am surprised, since this is one of the most direct proofs. Care to expand on the trouble you had while trying?

Comment: @Did The same issue really. If you approximate you get something like $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_i \int_{[a_i,b_i]} \sin (nx) \, dx$$ which converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, but then I still didn't understand how the integral of a dense subset gave us the integral for any $f \in L^1$

Comment: @AnthonyPeter I meant showing that the limit converges.

Comment: Well, denoting by $I_n(f)$ the integrals you are interested in, for every $g$ simple, one gets $$|I_n(f)|\leqslant |I_n(g)|+\int_\mathbb R|f(x)-g(x)|\,|\sin(nx)|\,dx\leqslant|I_n(g)|+\|f-g\|_1,$$ hence $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}|I_n(f)|\leqslant\limsup_{n\to\infty}|I_n(g)|+\|f-g\|_1=0+\|f-g\|_1,$$ and since the RHS can be made as small as one wants, the proof is over.

Comment: @Did Is it true then that $\mathcal{F}(f)$ is uniformly continuous w.r.t $L^1$ since if $||f-g||_{L^1} <\delta$, then $$| \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f \sin(nx)  \, dx - \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f \sin(nx)  \, dx | \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f-g||\sin(nx)| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f-g| \, dx = ||f-g||_{L^1},$$ or is this just a rewording of what you've shown? (p.s. sorry about the alignment, I missed a bracket.)

Comment: Yes this is merely rewriting the first step of the proof in my comment.

Comment: @Did But if it is uniformly continuous, why is the second step necessary? Is it not enough to say that we can just extend $\mathcal{F}(f)|_{\operatorname{simple}}$ to $L^1$?

Comment: This is playing with words: either one reproves this (and this is short and easy to do, as I showed) or one admits it, saying it is well known.

Comment: @Did Thank you for your help.